# Notepad ++ Multiple Number and Character Swap

Tags: notepad++

FNG here and I'm looking for some assistance in creating a logic that would be useful in moving a string that is to be named swapped and moved to the front of the line.

I have used the the following for name swap

^([^\r\n,]+)(,\h*)([^,\r\n]+)$

$3$2$1

John, Doe

Doe, John

I need the following adjustment

00111, 0123, 0001 John, Doe

Doe, John, 00111, 0123, 0001

Excuse my brevity

Comment: Your requirements are not at all clear. Brevity is good but the specification needs to be complete.

Comment: Instead of  00111, 0123, 0001 John, Doe.  I need the ending "name string" portion to move to the front of the numbers.  Ex:  Doe, John, 00111, 0123, 0001.                          Thank you in advance

Comment: I ended up using the following    ^([0-9]+)(,\h*)([0-9]+)(,\h*)([0-9]+)(,\h*)([^\r\n,]+)(,\h*)([^,\r\n]+)$   to complete the change swap of the strings and digits

Answer (score 0):

This could probably work...

```
^(\d+,) (\d+,) (\d+) (\w+,) (\w+)$
```

Replace with:

```
$5, $4 $1 $2 $3
```

https://regex101.com/r/gRsGLr/1

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)\h+([^,\r\n]+),\h+(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$3, $2, $1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
    (.+)            # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
    \h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    ([^,\r\n]+)     # group 2, 1 or more any character that is not comma or linebreak
    ,\h+            # a comma and 1 or more horizontal spaces
    (.+)            # group 3, 1 or more any character but newline
$
```

**Replacement:**

```
$3          # content of group 3
,           # comma & space
$2          # content of group 2
,           # comma & space
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]